# Precedence of comma operator

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  int a,b;
  a=3,1;
  b=(5,4);
  printf("%d",a+b);
}
```

I am new to C and am having trouble understanding the above program.  Can anyone please explain the program output?

Comment: What output?  You forgot to show it.

Comment: One issue is that, if you ask for an explanation of output, but don't actually show any, some might think that you did not compile/build/run your code at all and that your post is a no-effort homework dump.  To avoid that, include as much info as you can in questions.

Answer (score 6):

The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates each of its subexpressions in sequence, discarding the value of all but the rightmost subexpression, and evaluates to the rightmost subexpression.

This operator has the lowest precedence, lower that the assignment operator in fact.  So this:

```
a=3,1;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(a=3),1;
```

So `a` is assigned the value of `3`, then the value `1` is evaluated.  The full expression has the value `1`, but this value is discarded as it isn't assigned to anything.

In contrast:

```
b=(5,4);
```

The parenthesis cause the comma operator to evaluate first.  So `5` is evaluated and discarded, then `4` is evaluated and assigned to `b`.

So `a` has the value 3 and `b` has the value 4.  So the program prints `a+b` which is `7`.

Answer (score 3):

This expression statement

```
  a=3,1;
```

contains two operators. The first one is the assignment operator `a = 3` it assigns 3 to `a` the second operator is the comma operator. You can imagine it like
`( a = 3 ), 1`. That is it has two operands that are expressions `( a = 3 )` and `1`. The second expression is the value of integer literal `1` that has no effect.

Take into account that the assignment operator has higher priority than the comma operator.

In this expression statement

```
  b=(5,4);
```

there are also the same two operators: the assignment operator and the comma operator. But now the comma operator is enclosed in parentheses.  The value of the comma operator is the value of its second operand. So the expression with the comma operator `( 5, 4 )` yields `4`. This value is assigned to `b`.

And at last you have

```
printf("%d",a+b);
```

that outputs the sum of `a` and `b` that is equal to 3 + 4 = 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile it with -Wall option compiler will warn you:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:159:6: warning: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   a=3,1;
      ^
test.c:160:7: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   b=(5,4);
       ^
```

This explain you which value is taken as init value of `a` and `b` variable.

In this case `a=3 b=4`